# Filtering in INPUT chain didn't work for docker forwarded ports

Tags: iptables, docker

I have a Linux server running a docker application, it exposes the 80 port inside docker to 20080 on the host.

The server has IP address `10.10.10.10` and I need to block `10.10.10.11` from accessing the `10.10.10.10:20080` port.

However, adding a DROP on the INPUT chain didn't work, the port is still accessible. Any ideas?

Attached full iptables rules:

```
# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Thu Jul  6 22:26:24 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20080 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20080 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-643859f655c0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-643859f655c0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-643859f655c0 ! -o br-643859f655c0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-643859f655c0 -o br-643859f655c0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.4/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-643859f655c0 ! -o br-643859f655c0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-643859f655c0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul  6 22:26:24 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Thu Jul  6 22:26:24 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o br-643859f655c0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.4/32 -d 172.17.0.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i br-643859f655c0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:80
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20022 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4:22
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jul  6 22:26:24 2023
```

Comment: You need to add rules to the `FORWARD` chain.

Comment: @larsks added and it still not working

Comment: Drop destination port 80, not 20080. After DNAT destination IP and port is already changed.